# vi replaces with empty when searching

Tags: vim, cygwin, vi

In vi (from cygwin), when I do searching:

```
:%s/something
```

It just replaces the something with empty string like

```
:%s/something//  .
```

I've googled for a while but nothing really mentions this. Is there anything I should add to the .vimrc or .exrc to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: search is `:/something`

Comment: @matzeri, that does work, but the `:` is unnecessary.

Comment: @matzeri Now it works, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vi and vim, when you search for a pattern, you can search it again by simply typing `/`. It is understood that the previous pattern has to be used when no pattern is specified for searching.
(Though, you can press `n` for finding next occurence)

Same way, when you give a source (pattern) and leave the replacement in substitute command,  it assumes that the replacement is empty and hence the given pattern is replaced with no characters (in other words, the pattern is removed)

In your case, you should understand that `%` stand for whole file(buffer) and `s` for substitute. To search, you can simply use `/`, followed by a pattern. To substitute , you will use `:s`. You need not confuse searching and substituting. Hence, no need for such settings in ~/.exrc. Also, remember that `/` is enough to search the whole buffer and `%` isnt necessary with `/`. `/` searches the entire buffer implicitly.

You may also want to look at `:g/Pattern/`. Learn more about it by searching `:help global` or `:help :g` in command line.

Comment: Oh now it works. Thanks. I was just confused by those tutorials since they are always taking about search & replace.

Comment: I advice you to use vim with version greater than  7.2. Vim comes with so many awesome features and is better than vi. Your editing experience would be better with vim. :)

Comment: @SibiCoder Do you mean that the `/` stands for the search in his first command  `:%s/something` ?

Comment: @SibiCoder , I'm not sure about them. In some articles I saw they're just symlink different name thing.

Comment: @Meninx I didn't mean. ZISISNOTZIS seems to be a new user of vi and his question seems like he is confused about the usage of `%s` with search. He assumed that %s is for searching and while he searched with %s , it replaced the text with no characters (removed it). Now, I hope he is clear with search and substitute

Answer (score 2):

The format of a substitution in vim is as follows:

> :[range]s[ubstitute]/{pattern}/{string}/[flags] [count]

In your case you have omitted the string from the substitution command  and here what vim documentation stated about it:

> **If the {string} is omitted the substitute is done as if it's empty**. 
>   Thus the matched pattern is deleted.  **The separator after {pattern}
>   can also be left out then**.  Example: >
>           **:%s/TESTING This deletes "TESTING" from all lines, but only one per line.**
>
> For compatibility with Vi these two exceptions are allowed:
>   "/{string}/" and "\?{string}?" do the same as "//{string}/r".
>   "\&{string}&" does the same as "//{string}/".
>
> *E146*
>
> **Instead of the '/'** which surrounds the pattern and replacement string, **you can
>   use any other single-byte character, but not an alphanumeric
>   character**, '\', '"' or '|'.  This is useful if you want to include a
>   '/' in the search  pattern or replacement string.  Example: >
>           :s+/+//+

In other words `:%s/something` and `:%s;something` or `:%s,something` have all the same behavior because the `/` `;` and `,` in the last examples are considered **only as SIMPLE SEPARATOR**